# Native Mobile SetLanguage

Tags: genexus

Migre una KB desde Genexus 16U11 a Genexus 17U10. En un botón de un Panel (Native Mobile) tenia el código (**SetLanguage**) para poder cambiar de idioma y funcionaba bien. Ahora en **Genexus 17U10** cuando ejecuto esa linea **la app se cierra**, intente colocando Action.GoHome y ocurre lo mismo.

¿Alguna experiencia con esto?

Comment: Habria que identificar el "por que" se cierra la app. Para eso te recomiendo que prendas el debug. A nivel del objeto MAIN mobile, tenes una propiedad "Default Log Level", seteala con el valor "Debug" y ejecuta nuevamente. El log lo podes ver, en Android desde el monitor.bat (que se encuentra en SDK > tools), o directamente desde el Android Studio si lo tenes instalado. En iOS lo podes ver desde el XCode directamente. Ahi vas a poder entender mejor la causa que genera el crash y arreglar el problema. Saludos

Comment: Desde el monitor.bat del SDK de Android no aparecía mucha información o detalle del problema. Intente con una KB desde cero en la U10, U9 y U8... y en la que funciono fue el U8. Debe ser un bug de las versiones de Genexus 17 mayores a la U8.